# Blazor component library accessible only in Development environment

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

To reproduce - create new (server side) Blazor project.
Then create new RazorComponentLibrary.
All with default, minimalistic options.
In the component library, in directory `wwwroot/js` create any JavaScript file.
Then, in the Blazor project, reference the component library, and add an appropriate line to `Pages/_Host.cshtml` file, in my case it's:

```html
<script src="_content/RazorClassLibrary1/js/test.js"></script>
```

Change project properties, Debug section, to launch Project.
Run the project in the browser.

Anything will show up in the browser, the console log is clear.

Then create a file appsettings.Production.json. Let it be empty.
Add profile "Production" (copy your existing default profile).
Change `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable value to "Production" (or antything else).

Run the project again. Watch the browser console. You should get 404 for it can't find the referenced JavaScript file.

WHY?

Is is a bug in Blazor, or is a special voodoo to make when creating an environment other than "Development"?

Comment: Make sure you do a Rebuild in VS. If that doesn't work analyze the requested path (404) with what's in the output \bin

Comment: @HenkHolterman I rebuilt the solution. In the `output/bin` directory the files from `wwwroot` directories are not included. None of them. But when I set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable to "Development" - suddenly the browser sees all those files. The problem doesn't occur when publishing the project - because published project contains `wwwroot` files. But that's not how VS debugging works.